# React horizontal Scrolling Menu?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, horizontal-scrolling

I am building a `nextjs` application. In my project I am not using `TypeScript`. I am using `Javascript`. I need a horizontal scroll on mouse wheel and also on touch. I haven't find any react packages. But I find one react package - [`react-horizontal-scrolling-menu`](https://github.com/asmyshlyaev177/react-horizontal-scrolling-menu). I see all demo. It perfect for my project. But I am facing one problem. Al of it's example create in `TypeScript`. But I am not using `typeScript`. If I copy the code, Then I get many error?

https://codesandbox.io/s/no-scrollbar-and-buttons-position-c3kn5?file=/src/index.tsx

In this situation, What I have to do. I am not understanding?

Please can anyone help me. I am facing this issue over 10 days. Please do not dislike or close my questions.

Comment: I opened the "code sandbox" example and I didn't face any issues! Please attach the error to your question. In addition, If you want to add any ts or tsx file directly to your js project (not as a dependency), then you have to add typescript configs in your nextjs project.

Comment: It is not my codeSandbox. I want to tell, This codesandbox give example in typeScript. But I need in javascript.

Comment: If you can, please convert this codesandbox example into a javscript (.js ). Please.

Comment: Please please please. I really need it. Please.

Comment: Hello @Mohammad

Comment: please accept my answer if it's what you wantet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converted to JavaScript. You only needed to remove types and change `tsx`, `ts` to `jsx`, `js`.

https://codesandbox.io/s/no-scrollbar-and-buttons-on-bottom-forked-m2wci

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get rid of every type definition of typescript. Every type in TypeScript is written after the variable name behind ":". So, in the codesandbox example, remove things like ": number" or ": void" at the end of functions.

Edit: im on mobile now, so i can't send you the Javascript code. The things you should look for are on line 17, 20 and 57. Hope the helps you.

Comment: Not working! I am try it. When I remove type then not working scroll on wheel!

Comment: Can you give a codesandbox example?

Comment: I can't understand what change i have to do on line 17?

Comment: Remove it this line in index.tsx. It's a type declaration.

Comment: Then it is not working. I mean when I remove it, Then horizontal scrolling not working on mouse wheel.

Comment: Please help me. I am still not understanding!

Answer (score 0):

I am using also the component for my project which not typescript. As someone suggested I just removed the type definitons in the Arrow function.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).